# ArcGIS PostgreSQL Trigger

Tags: arcmap, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, sql

I currently have a trigger defined in my database which executes when my edits in ArcMap are saved using the `AFTER INSERT ON` method.

Is there anyway to execute this trigger without having to select Save Edits in ArcMap? I have tried both `BEFORE INSERT` and `UPDATE` as well.

Comment: I don't think so. When you "Save edits" ArcMap is actually pushing data to the underlying database. If you don't hit that "Save edits" button in ArcMap, nothing is happening server-side. Which means it doesn't matter if you use BEFORE or AFTER insert/update/delete.

Comment: Triggers on versioned geodatabases are problematic, but a trigger on edits *without* an explicit commit would lead to data corruption.